# Is there any way to make the Government not find out geolocation from the hoster?

Tags: vpn, server, geolocation

The government can find servers very quickly by contacting the hoster that hosts your VPN server, and the service provider might give your IP address.

But what if I use `torsocks ssh -d`? I don't know if it's like that, but whonix gateway + port forward.

Comment: VPN and Tor are two different things, aren't they?

Comment: I've tried to make sense of this question, but I think it needs a re-write for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Tor hidden service. If the SSH server is only accessible in the Tor network, there's no contact information on who hosts it, so nobody to the government to contact.

The security of it depends on your operation security, and on how determined is the adversary on finding you.